# Get the index of an object in numpy array that is object specific? Use array as index to get specific index combination?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a function to create the Levi-Civita tensor in an arbitrary number of dimensions. Since the tensor is sparse, I have created an n-dimensional array of zeros with numpy.zeros and plan to only change those values that need to be changed.

The values of the components in the Levi-Civita tensor are index specific. If any two indices are equal, the value is 0. If the indices represent an "even permutation" meaning they increase in value - with "looping" allowed (e.g. eps_1,2,3 or eps_2,3,1 or eps_3,1,2) - then the value is 1. If the indices represent an "odd permutation" meaning they decrease in value - with "looping" allowed (e.g. eps_3,2,1 or eps_2,1,3 or eps_1,3,2) - then the value is -1.

This is easy enough in 3 dimensions with three for loops, but I'm unsure how to do it in an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Here is my code to create an n^n sized matrix.

```
size = 3

size_array = size*np.ones((size), dtype=np.int32)

epsilon = np.zeros((size_array), dtype=np.float64)
```

One of my ideas was to iterate through the array using nditer, find the index of each element, check for even and odd permutations - not quite sure how to do that yet given the "looping" nature of it, and change those values accordingly. So:

```
for element in np.nditer(epsilon):
    # Get element's index
    # Figure out if permutation is even, odd, or two indices are the same
    # Change element values accordingly
```

The problem is I don't know how to check the index of the value "element" above. The only things I've found finds the index of a certain value rather than the object being passed itself. I would like to know that the specific "0." value being passed is at index [0, 0, 0...] rather than all of the places where the value 0. is in the array.

Alternatively, and probably more efficiently, I was wondering if there was any way to use an array to get a specific index rather than multiple indices. For example, for the array:

```
epsilon = np.array([[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]])
```

epsilon[0, 1] gives the value 12 - this is what I want, the value corresponding to the index 0, 1.

Whereas, for the same array:

```
epsilon = np.array([[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]])
a = [0, 1]
```

epsilon[a] gives array([[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23]]) - i.e. the first two rows of the array - a slice.

This way I could use np.arange to increase the value by one and find the even permutations (still need to figure out the "looping") and find the odd permutations by using np.arange to decrease the value by one. Then I won't have to iterate through every element in the arbitrarily sized array.

If anyone has any ideas here I would greatly appreciate it. I am aware that there is a function for this within sympy, but I'm trying to write this myself.

EDIT:
So I still haven't figured out my first question and at least as of now I do not need to - but I am still curious about it.

I have figured out my second. I guess what I needed was a bit of sleep, because the documentation states to use tuples for "Dealing with variable numbers of indices within programs." Here is my solution for anyone interested. I'm sure there are better, more efficient solutions, but no uses of lists or tuples are particularly large. This is also (I imagine) worlds faster than iterating through every value.

```
import numpy as np

def levi_civita(size):
    size_array = size*np.ones((size), dtype=np.int32)
    epsilon = np.zeros((size_array), dtype=np.float64)

    even = list(np.arange(0, size, 1))
    odd = list(np.arange(size-1, -1, -1))

    for i in range(0, size):
        even.insert(0, even.pop())
        epsilon[tuple(even)] = 1
    
        odd.insert(0, odd.pop())
        epsilon[tuple(odd)] = -1
    
    return epsilon
```

EDIT 2: To better explain my first question, I will try to give an example. Say I have the 3x3 array of zeros given by:

```
arr = np.zeros((3,3))
```

And then I iterate through the array using nditer:

```
for element in np.nditer(arr):
    # Get element's index
```

I would like to be able to get the index of the current element being passed through the loop. I know that I could use np.where to find every place where the value is 0., but that's not what I want to know. I want to know what the index of the current object called "element" is. So, for a made up method called "madeupindex" the following code:

```
for element in np.nditer(arr):
    print(element.madeupindex()
```

Would output:

```
(0,0)
(0,1)
(0,2)
(1,0)
(1,1)
(1,2)
(2,0)
(2,1)
(2,2)
```

Regardless of whatever value element is. I'm guessing I am going to have to take a closer look into enumerate - at least as one possible solution.

Comment: can you add simple reproducible example with desired result?

Comment: So I figured out my second question - I must have missed it in the docs last night. See my edit of details. I'lll add a second edit trying to better explain my first question.